# AngularJS - ngRepeat with multiple object types

Tags: javascript, dom, polymorphism, angularjs, rendering

I have a list of items. An item can be a number of things, let's say the list is something like so :

```
[userObject , vehicleObject , userObject , animalObject , animalObject]
```

Now I want to render the list with ngRepeat directive that will use a template according to the type of the object (Polymorphic rendering). can this be done?

maybe something like (**ng-use** is an **hypothetically** directive):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
       <img ng-use="item.type == 'user'" ng-src="item.src">
       <a ng-use="item.type == 'vehicle'">{{item.link}}</a>
       <span ng-use="item.type == 'animal'">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items" ng-switch="item.type">
       <img ng-switch-when="user" ng-src="item.src">
       <a ng-switch-when="vehicle">{{item.link}}</a>
       <span ng-switch-when="animal">{{item.name}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

API reference:
http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch

Comment: one more thing ... can you merge cases, meaning something like  ng-switch-when="'user'||'animal'"?

Comment: No you can't do that. Btw, when using `ng-switch-when` you shouldn't use extra `''` (contrary to my first answer), and angular handles the attribute values as strings. here is the related source code: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js

Comment: Thanks for that, very elaborating

Comment: This relies on the item object having a field "type"... what if your object doesn't have that?

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't use ng-switch, it does get round the problem of not having a *type* field, which @DotNetHaggis pointed out.

```
<div ng-repeat="field in fields">
    <div ng-if="field.user !== undefined">user info</div>
    <div ng-if="field.vehicle !== undefined">vehicle info</div>
    <div ng-if="field.animal !== undefined">animal info</div>
</div>
```