# Make a render condition with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know how to make a **view** condition in AngularJS, that will display or hide dom element dependent on the condition:

```
<div ng-show="{{isTrue}}">Some content</div>
```

but how do I create a **render** condition that determines whether to render or not the div?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**Update for angularjs 1.1.5 and above users (not supported in 1.0.7):**

> Related commit:
>   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/2f96fbd17577685bc013a4f7ced06664af253944

Angular now have a conditional rendering directive: `ngIf`.

Usage:

```
<div ng-if="conditional_expression"></div>
```

> Note that when an element is removed using ngIf its scope is destroyed and a new scope  is created when the element is restored

[Documentation: directive-ngIf](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf)

**For legacy angularjs users:**

`ngShow` directive conditionally hides/shows the element. This is going to be changed in one of the new stable releases, it is now available in the `unstable` release as with `1.1.5`.

If you want to conditionally add/remove items on DOM, use can use `ngSwitch`.

```
<div ng-switch="showMe">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">Hello!</div>
</div>
```

Actually, this directive has been created for handling cases for more than 1, but you can use it that way too. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425497/angularjs-ngrepeat-with-multiple-object-types/14425547#14425547) answer for examples of more sophisticated usages.

Comment: If 'ng-if' is false, DOM is rendered in load but have possible not be rendered?

Answer (score 2):

Recommended way is to use **ng-include**

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
     <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <tt>{{template.url}}</tt>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-include src="template.url"></div>
  </div>


  <!-- template1.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template1.html">
    Content of template1.html
  </script>

  <!-- template2.html -->
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="template2.html">
    Content of template2.html
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is it recommended? This seems to me like an overkill for small html fragments. Your fiddle doesn't work, by the way.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two ways of doing that:

- render some partial using templating
- use simple expression with conditional rendering function (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKT65/) and description below)

For simple components, I recommend sticking to the rendering function. Very easy to understand.

```
$scope.render = function(condition) {        
   return condition ? "This is rendered when condition == TRUE" : "This is rendered when condition == FALSE";
};
```

and simply include it in your HTML, like so:

```
{{render(true)}}
```

You can also wrap this up with angular directive, which will give you very nice markup and unlimited possibilities!

Comment: this is a nice approach. but I was really expecting something elegant such as ng-render="{{condition}}" to make it really simple and easy

Comment: Please read my answer carefully - you can wrap it up with directive, which will give you exactly what you need - a clean markup, like so: `<conditional-renderer condition="someValue == true">...`
I don't think Angular provides this out of the box.

Comment: Creating a rendering directive is not that simple. OP means that he would like to change the dom structure, and the directive needs to watch the conditional property and destroy scope and release related sources or you are likely to leak into memory.

Comment: This is not correct, You need to compile the return value. This is even against the best practice of "not doing DOM manipulation in controller". Best way is to use ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.com/) `if` directive. I believe this would serve you purpose well.

Comment: Looks like this was removed from Angular UI. No clue why.

Comment: @bmoeskau possibly because it ngif is now part of AngularJS as of v1.1.5

Comment: Because the AngularJS core is catching up.