# ng-if is not working under nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am getting some server response data in two different JSON as:

```
userlist{id,name,type...}
and 
tasklist{assign_to,tester,title,description...}
```

here, I need to show the task of the corresponding user.

so, I have nested the tasklist under the userlist using ng-repeat as:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in userList">
  <table>          
      <tr><th>Name </th><td>{{user.name}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Type </th><td>{{user.type}}</td></tr>          
  </table> 
  <div ng-repeat="task in taskList">
   <div ng-if="task.assign_to==user.id || task.tester==user.id">
    <table>          
      <tr><th>Title </th><td>{{task.title}}</td></tr>
      <tr><th>Task Desc </th><td>{{task.description}}</td></tr>          
    </table> 
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

but it's not working. As all the tasks are showing for every user.(Means ng-if is not working).

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: your code is working for me..can you explain more to getting a problem.

Comment: @ Arjun... which version of Angular JS you are using ?

Comment: I am using (angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js). Is this not supported ?

Comment: ngIf is not supported in 1.0.7. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475284/make-a-render-condition-with-angularjs

Comment: Yeah @Arjun is right , use updated angular,js file in your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All it was about the version actually. 1.0.7 doesn't support ng-if. Hence, 1.1.5 worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Angularjs code is case-sensitive. Please check variable name in scope. From the code you pasted above, the two lists should be :
**userlist**{id,name,type...}
and 
**tasklist**{assign_to,tester,title,description...}

Use same in HTML. I think you are using **taskList** and **userList** (with capital L, use same name in JS and html)