# Conditional rendering on angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I used to work with backbone and handlebars and was able to do things like

```
{{ if condition }}
  <div class="container">
{{ endif }}

  more html

{{ if condition }}
  </div>
{{ endif}}
```

I know I can use ng-if but I want to display conditionally  an element opening and closing  not the whole element.

Comment: angular only deals with full elements when working within html source, not html fragments. Use directives for more advanced templating

Comment: yup, write a directive

Comment: Anyway, that's sound like a very bad thing to do!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make a render condition with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14475284/make-a-render-condition-with-angularjs)

Answer (score 2):

You can write a `directive` and accomplish exactly what you want, but I think a better way to do things is to **create** a div(**without conditions** - since every open div element has to have a closing element) and to add dynamic content inside using `ng-if`:

```
<div>
  <div ng-if="cond1"></div>
  <div ng-if="cond2"></div>
  <!-- ETC...... -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and best way to do this by using "ng-if" attribute for any HTML element that you want to render on the basis of some condition that you can manupulate in your controller as per your need.

For example:

```
<div ng-if = "expression">
</div>
```

This expression should be evaluate to be boolean i.e. either true or false, here you can specify multiple condition also which should be evaluate to true or false.

For multiple condition example check out this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/820/

Check out this example in example section of "ngif doc":

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf