# Select a Directive Dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a couple of directives and I want to select each one for the result of the `ng-repeat`.

```
<div class="{{field.type_desc}}"  ng-repeat="field in row.fields"></div>
```

and this is the code in the controller

```
app.directive('Textbox', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link : function (scope,element)
    {
        formFieldTemplate= $('<input>').attr('type','password'); 
        $compile(formFieldTemplate)(scope); 
        var formListElement = $(element);
        formListElement.append(formFieldTemplate);
    }
}
})
```

After the page load I can see in the HTML the right class, but still I can't see the directive.

Thank you for your help

Comment: This one surprised me. I also tried it with variations of ng-class and it didn't work either.

Comment: I thought it would be related to the fact that ng-repeat is terminal and has a priority of 1000, whereas by default the priority is zero. that means that your directive should not trigger because ng-repeat goes first and cuts the compilation process (terminal). I tried it here but it is not working http://plnkr.co/edit/IRFLfQKRcp1kxuvhGNdE?p=preview

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425497/angularjs-ngrepeat-with-multiple-object-types/14425547#14425547

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a few things for dynamic generation of directives:

```
var myNewDirectiveScope = $scope.$new();
myNewDirectiveScope.myProperty = 'Some value';

var myDirective = $compile('<div my-directive-name my-property="myProperty"></div>');

var myDirectiveElement = myDirective(myNewDirectiveScope);

$(window.document.body).append(myDirectiveElement);
```

So first I'm creating a new scope.  Then I'm assigning the string 'Some value' to a property of that scope.

I then provide compile with a string template with the name of the directive and the property that points to myProperty which is on the scope that you created.  This returns a function that once called with a scope will return the element that you can actually append on your page.

So in your case it might be:

```
app.directive('Textbox', function($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'C',
    link : function (scope,element)
    {
        var formFieldTemplate = '<input type="password" />';

        var directive = $compile(formFieldTemplate);

        var formListElement = directive(scope);

        formListElement.append(formFieldTemplate);
    }
}
})
```